# How to CONCATENATE using text with double quotes, square and curly brackets

Tags: excel-formula, concatenation

I'm trying to create a CONCATENATE formula to create the following:

```
[{"record_id":"0","from_week":"04\/08\/2024","to_week":"06\/17\/2024"}]
```

In which the day, month and year:

```
04 
08 
2024 
06 
17
2024
```

would be pulled and concatenated from other cells. The issue I'm running into is that I have to replace the quote marks with CHAR(34) and it seems like the square [] brackets and curly {} brackets are also not accepted as concatenatable characters.  Already the number of CHAR(34) needed seems a bit extreme.

Comment: Try `="[{""record_id"":""0"",""from_week"":"""&TEXT(A1,"0#")&"\/"&TEXT(A2,"0#")&"\/"&A3&""",""to_week"":"""&TEXT(A4,"0#")&"\/"&TEXT(A5,"0#")&"\/"&A6&"""}]"`. If your list separator is a semicolon, replace only the four commas in the `TEXT()` expressions with semicolons.

Comment: Not that elegant as @VBasic2008 Sir's `=LET(a, TEXT(BYROW(WRAPROWS(B2:B7,3),CONCAT),"00\/00\/0000"), b, TAKE(a,1), c,TAKE(a,-1),"[{""record_id"":""0"",""from_week"":"""&b&""",""to_week"":"""&c&"""}]")`

Comment: Consider using `LET()` and assign your special characters to variables, Then set up your `CONCAT()` function in the calculation argument.